# Evaluate the Surface Integral $xyz$ $dS$ where $S$ is the surface defined by $2y=\sqrt{9-x}$, $x>0$, and between $z=0$ and $z=3$.

Tags: surface-integrals

Evaluate the Surface Integral $xyz$ $dS$ where $S$ is the surface defined by $2y=\sqrt{9-x}$, $x>0$, and between $z=0$ and $z=3$.

Don't even know where to start with this question.

Comment: An idea: begin by parametrizing your surface, say $$r(u,v)=\left(u,\,\frac{\sqrt{9-u}}2,\,v\right)\;,\;\;0\le u\le 9\;,\;\;0\le v\le 3$$ and now do the vectorial product $$r'_u\times r'_v$$ and take its norm. Finally, according to your parameters intervals, your integral is $$\int\int_A x(u,v)y(u,v)z(u,v)\cdot ||r'_u\times r'_v|| dA$$ with $\;A\;$ the zone on the $\;uv-$plane determined by the parameters and $\;x,y,z\;$ are given according to the parametrization $\;r(u,v)\;$

Comment: When it comes to Mathjax, generally two dollar signs should be next to each other only to put math in display mode (i.e., on its own line). So rather than `$xyz$ $dS`, $xyz\ dS$ should be accomplished with some kind of whitespace command, like `xyz\ dS`, `xyz\,dS`, or `$xyz~dS$`, things like that @JKnecht